# Using an array for data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, highcharts

So when using the data I want in high charts I can just type it in as such and it works:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [0.818883519277839, 0.8118310020160356, 0.8292750491048191, 0.8207364844853503, 0.8187873450691459, 0.8098962769401326, 0.8060550491107373, 0.7960675107192992, 0.7798022181293245, 0.7747131667969733, 0.77704753581292, 0.780881503288139, 0.7808802272036436, 0.7828232760186384, 0.7745154579263632, 0.7858447215087305, 0.7903196602781966, 0.7904203695573747, 0.7842096993261638, 0.7736738976551895]
        }]
    });
});
```

However, when I try to replace it with a for-loop that goes through my array it doesn't work. Is there a proper way for using an array for data?

For instance:

```
myArray = [0.818883519277839, 0.8118310020160356, 0.8292750491048191, 0.8207364844853503, 0.8187873450691459, 0.8098962769401326, 0.8060550491107373, 0.7960675107192992, 0.7798022181293245, 0.7747131667969733, 0.77704753581292, 0.780881503288139, 0.7808802272036436, 0.7828232760186384, 0.7745154579263632, 0.7858447215087305, 0.7903196602781966, 0.7904203695573747, 0.7842096993261638, 0.7736738976551895]
```

and then

```
       series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: myArray,
        }]
```

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like it should work. Can you re-produce the problem in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Check your errors in the console (developer tools in browser). Let me know if you use a json to get data or it is external array only ?

Answer (score 0):

What are your y-axis values?

Also, the data for the x-axis must be ordered increasingly for highcharts to work properly. Check your console to see if there are any errors as stated by Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you're trying to do it.
See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4arw1se/

```
series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: myArray
    }]
```

Can you post the function you're using to generate the data array?